# Oracle SQL Comparing via DECODE

Tags: sql, oracle, nvl

I try to get something in Oracle, if the `commission` is greater than `0.2` I would like to get `'GOOD'`, otherwise `'BAD'`. And also if the `commission is null` I want to get `0`. I know that is with `NVL`, but something get wrong with syntax. Can you help me?

```
SELECT LAST_NAME,
       SALARY,
       DECODE(
              NVL(COMMISSION_PCT),
              COMMISSION_PCT < 0,2, 'BAD', COMMISSION_PCT > 0,2, 'GOOD'
            ) CommissionResult
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Comment: `DECODE` doesn't directly support comparison operators, you would need to evaluate the expressions using `SIGN`.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, `0.2` should be written as `0.2`, not `0,2`. But most importantly, `decode` is not suitable for this case.

In this case (and all other cases where you *could* use decode), you can use `case`, which is more flexible and a more verbose so it is easier to read too.

```
SELECT LAST_NAME,SALARY,
CASE WHEN NVL(COMMISSION_PCT) < 0.2 THEN
  'BAD'
WHEN COMMISSION_PCT > 0.2 THEN 
  'GOOD'
END as CommissionResult
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

In your this case, you will get `NULL` when the percentage is exactly 0.2. Maybe you just need an `ELSE` clause instead:

```
SELECT LAST_NAME,SALARY,
CASE WHEN NVL(COMMISSION_PCT) < 0.2 THEN
  'BAD'
ELSE
  'GOOD'
END as CommissionResult
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Comment: I know it's easier with CASE construction,but I have a exam and there is written to make it with DECODE,So I need a solution with  DECODE.Thanks for this although.

Comment: @razi3lbr **DECODE** doesn't directly support comparison operators, you would need to evaluate the expressions using **SIGN**.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECODE(
          NVL(COMMISSION_PCT),
          COMMISSION_PCT < 0,2,'BAD',COMMISSION_PCT > 0,2,'GOOD'
        )
```

Your query is syntactically incorrect.

- `NVL` syntax is incomplete
- You have a typo in the decimal number, a comma instead of dot.
- **DECODE** syntax doesn't support comparisons.

For your requirement, you could use **CASE** expression which is verbose and easy to interpret.

Using **CASE**

For example, using the standard **EMP** table in SCOTT schema:

```
SQL> SELECT ename,
  2    sal,
  3    CASE
  4      WHEN NVL(comm, 0) < 0.2
  5      THEN 'BAD'
  6      WHEN NVL(comm, 0) > 0.2
  7      THEN 'GOOD'
  8    END CommissionResult
  9  FROM emp;

ENAME             SAL COMM
---------- ---------- ----
SMITH             800 BAD
ALLEN            1600 GOOD
WARD             1250 GOOD
JONES            2975 BAD
MARTIN           1250 GOOD
BLAKE            2850 BAD
CLARK            2450 BAD
SCOTT            3000 BAD
KING             5000 BAD
TURNER           1500 BAD
ADAMS            1100 BAD
JAMES             950 BAD
FORD             3000 BAD
MILLER           1300 BAD

14 rows selected.
```

However, if you must use **DECODE**, then you need to use **SIGN** to have the same functionality.

Using **DECODE**

```
SQL> SELECT ename,
  2    sal,
  3    DECODE( SIGN(NVL(comm, 0) - 0.2), -1, 'BAD', +1, 'GOOD') CommissionResult
  4  FROM emp;

ENAME             SAL COMM
---------- ---------- ----
SMITH             800 BAD
ALLEN            1600 GOOD
WARD             1250 GOOD
JONES            2975 BAD
MARTIN           1250 GOOD
BLAKE            2850 BAD
CLARK            2450 BAD
SCOTT            3000 BAD
KING             5000 BAD
TURNER           1500 BAD
ADAMS            1100 BAD
JAMES             950 BAD
FORD             3000 BAD
MILLER           1300 BAD

14 rows selected.
```